# OLE2 signature is invalid when trying to open my XLS file

Tags: ruby, excel, spreadsheet, roo

I'm using the Roo gem, and the following code:

```
Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
```

This raises the following exception:

```
Ole::Storage::FormatError: OLE2 signature is invalid
```

The file I'm using its a .xls, when I open it and re-saved it from LibreOffice it just works. Why is that?